# Fluid Baking Stops

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking

I'm trying to bake this fluid simulation but when i click in **Bake**, it starts baking and like 30 seconds later it stops and the domain reamins as solid cube (the *cache_fluid* folder remains empty too).

I will put my blend file here if someone can help me solve this problem:  https://we.tl/ZBAF9qe6Y3

Comment: What are your PC specs?

Comment: Like GPU and CPU, RAM...

Comment: CPU: i7-4790K
RAM: 16GB

Comment: GPU: ASUS R9 280X

Comment: Well, it can't be your system...

Comment: So why you asked about my specs then??

Comment: Is this really the file that won't bake? I tried it with both 2.69 and 2.76, and it baked that just fine. Sure, your domain is way larger than it needs to be, but that shouldn't cause baking to stop. Whatever the problem is, it's on your side.